# convert .ipynb file to .py file

Tags: python, python-3.9

I am trying to convert jupyter notebook file to py. so basically converting it from .ipynb to .py.
First I tried going in file>download as .py and it is showing me an error
500:Internal Server error

then i tried

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to script "HOURLY_PERFORMANCE.ipynb"
```

error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'template_paths'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts\jupyter-nbconvert.EXE\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 254, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 350, in start
    self.convert_notebooks()
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 518, in convert_notebooks
    cls = get_exporter(self.export_format)
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\base.py", line 102, in get_exporter
    if getattr(exporter(config=config), 'enabled', True):
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\templateexporter.py", line 325, in __init__
    super().__init__(config=config, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\exporter.py", line 114, in __init__
    self._init_preprocessors()
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\templateexporter.py", line 491, in _init_preprocessors
    conf = self._get_conf()
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\templateexporter.py", line 507, in _get_conf
    for path in map(Path, self.template_paths):
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 575, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 538, in get
    default = obj.trait_defaults(self.name)
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1578, in trait_defaults
    return self._get_trait_default_generator(names[0])(self)
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 975, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\templateexporter.py", line 518, in _template_paths
    template_names = self.get_template_names()
  File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\templateexporter.py", line 601, in get_template_names
    raise ValueError('No template sub-directory with name %r found in the following paths:\n\t%s' % (base_template, paths))
ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'script' found in the following paths:
    C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
    c:\program files\python39\share\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
```

please help how can I do it.

Comment: Jupyter itself has a option do download the notebook in .py file. Did you tried that?

Comment: Upload to google colab and then try to download as .py

Comment: i upgraded colab, not working same issue